# PyVista: Getting mesh indices (triangles)

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, pyvista

I was originally using https://github.com/pmneila/PyMCubes which conveniently outputs the mesh points and indices but have since moved to PyVista since for whatever reason PyMCubes applied some sort of weird transformation that isn't ideal. How can I extract the same information from PyVista?

For a simple sphere:

```
def sphere(x, y, z):
    scalar = 8 * np.ones(len(x*y*z))
    dist = (x**2 + y**2 + z**2)**(1/2)
    scalar[(dist >= 1**2) | (dist <= 0.75**2) | (z <= 0)] = 0
    return scalar

# create a uniform grid to sample the function with
n = 100
x_min, y_min, z_min = -2, -2, -2
grid = pv.ImageData(
    dimensions=(n, n, n),
    spacing=(abs(x_min) / n * 2, abs(y_min) / n * 2, abs(z_min) / n * 2),
    origin=(x_min, y_min, z_min),
)

x, y, z = grid.points.T

values = sphere(x, y, z)

fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, name='inner', mode='markers', marker=dict(size=values)),])
# fig.show(renderer='browser')

mesh = grid.contour([1], values, method='marching_cubes').smooth()
dist = np.linalg.norm(mesh.points, axis=1)
mesh.plot(scalars=dist, smooth_shading=True, specular=1, opacity=0.3, cmap="plasma", show_scalar_bar=False)

triangulated = mesh.extract_surface()
triangles = triangulated.surface_indices().reshape(-1, 3)
vertices = mesh.points
```

The vertices and mesh points I have grabbed definitely do not correspond to each other since plotting them independently of PyVista generates garbage.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you're asking exactly, and your code example is not a [mcve]. If you want triangle face indices with corresponding points: yeah, you have to take the `.points` of the same mesh you're querying the triangles of. `surface_indices()` is new to me but for a polydata (e.g. `triangulated`) you can use [`regular_faces`](https://docs.pyvista.org/version/stable/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyData.regular_faces.html#pyvista.PolyData.regular_faces) to get the face indices. And use the same `triangulated.points` to get corresponding points. Does that do what you expect?

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні `regular_faces` was what I was looking for! Thank you!